# Jenkins inside a container do not find docker command

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run a container inside another. Where the first it's based in a jenkins image and the second in a gcc image (only for test).

That's the steps I maked:

1. I upped a container jenkins based in the image `jenkins/jenkins` with the docker command:

   - `docker run -it -p 1234:8080 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -u 0 jenkins/jenkins`
   - where `jenkins_home` is a volume created with the command: `docker volume create jenkins_home`
2. I installed the plugins Docker, Docker Slaves and Docker Pipeline.
3. I created a pipeline job:

```
pipeline {
    stages {        
        stage('Container') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'gcc'
                    args '-v ${nomedocurso}:/curso/'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'ls -l'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- In this case, the error is jenkins not find docker:

  > + docker inspect -f . gcc /var/jenkins_home/workspace/curso-c@2@tmp/durable-ee333f1e/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/curso-c@2@tmp/durable-ee333f1e/script.sh: docker: not found
- I tried to include the `label` parameter:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'docker' 
    }
    stages {        
        stage('Container') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    label 'docker'
                    image 'gcc'
                    args '-v ${nomedocurso}:/curso/'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'ls -l'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- But jenkins still continued complaining:

> Still waiting to schedule task
>   ‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘docker’

---

- Why docker do not be find by the jenkins?
- How do I set up and run a pipeline with docker in one of the stages?

Comment: Jenkins needs a `docker` binary installed in its runtime environment.  Bind-mounting the Docker socket isn’t enough on its own.

Comment: @DavidMaze i'm using groovy, not jenkinsfile. what I do in that case????